# Passing array to props but getting error while iterating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm passing an array of data to a functional component in reactjs as given below

```
<Route
  path="/tags"
  component={() => <Tag {...props.Tags} />}
/>
```

and props.Tags has values like

```
[
  {
    "Tags":"Tag1"
  },
  {
    "Tags":"Tag2"
  }
]
```

In Tag.js, when I do a `foreach` or `map` i'm getting this error.

```
const tag = (props) => {
  props.map(p => {
    console.log(p);
  }
...
}
```

error message

`TypeError: props.forEach is not a function`
or
`TypeError: props.map is not a function`

How to iterate an array passed as props?

Comment: The error means that `props` is not an array like you think it is. I cannot offer any more help than that until you provide a [mcve] that reproduce the exact error. In particular, we need context for where this `const tag` variable is assigned. What function is this code in? Please show this.

Comment: And what are you trying to do with `<Tag {...props.Tags} />`. If `props.Tags` is an array, this makes no sense. You might need to do `<Tag tags=props.Tags>` instead? But this is a strange choice if you want to create several `Tag` elements instead of just one.

Comment: That's just an example.

Comment: It's an invalid example. For us to help you, we need code that actually reproduces the error you are asking about and doesn't have any additional errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that props is not an array but an object like this:

```
{
  Tags: "Tags2"
}
```

You should pass your `tags` prop (for props is best practice to use lowercase names) in this way:

```
<Tags items={["tag1", "tag2"]} />
```

If you actually want to iterate props, by the way, you can use something like:

```
Object.keys(props).map(prop => props[prop]) // Do something with the prop
```

Comment: Or following the example given, something like `<Tags tags=props.tags>`.